# SteamCMD Failed to get application info app

Tags: steam

I am trying to push my first build to a depot and I keep getting this error and I can't figure out why.

```
Logged in OK
Waiting for license info...OK
[2015-05-17 20:11:58]: ERROR! Failed to get application info for app <appID> (check login and subscription)
```

I am using SteamCMD obviously, and I am logging in with the account that I use to login to Steamworks.

Has anyone had this problem before? If so, what is the fix? Thanks.

Comment: This appears to mean you personally don't have the rights (by Steam's discretion) to upload to the appID of your game. If you aren't the primary developer on the SteamWorks page, that might be one cause (and it seems to be my issue). How to fix this, I do not know yet. I'm trying to get it resolved myself and will get back to you. If you've figure this out in the three months between asking and now, please answer your own question, so that I may solve this too.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a configuration problem on Steam's side. If you contact them through the [SteamDev Group](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks/discussions/0/618456760266200621/) discussion on this error. That link goes to a private page for Steam Developers, so anyone with this problem should already have access and can follow the link. If you contact them, it looks like they can get it resolved fairly quickly. On the order of 24 hours.